# Who created humans?

Tags: genesis

If the word Elohim is plural does that mean we were created by gods (plural with small g)? If Genesis happened 2,000 years ago and Anunnaki, hindu gods etc have been on earth longer, who created them and how did they end up on planet earth??

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, as asked your question isn't a good fit for this site, since there could be many different answers depending on the perspective of the answerer, which isn't what this site is for. Please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394) and: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Christian Bible, and general Christian belief, God created Man in his image and likeness.  First Adam and then Eve.  This is clearly stated in the Book of Genesis.  (The Christian Bible does not address, nor does it need to account for, Hindu belief.  That is for Hindu sacred texts to address).

The accounts in Genesis happened a long time ago: [a bit over six thousand years ago if one accepts some Young Earth Creationist positions](https://answersingenesis.org/age-of-the-earth/how-old-is-the-earth/), 10-12,000 years ago according to others, or "a long time ago" according to most Christians.  Your "2000 years ago" for humans being created by God is an incorrect assertion about Christian belief.  (It was about 2000 years ago that Jesus was born, lived, and died).

Genesis Book 1:

> 26 Then God said: "Let us make man in our image, after our likeness.
>   Let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, the birds of the air,
>   and the cattle, and over all the wild animals and all the creatures
>   that crawl on the ground."   27 God created man in his image; in the
>   divine image he created him; male and female he created them.   28 God
>   blessed them, saying: "**Be fertile and multiply;** fill the earth and
>   subdue it. Have dominion over the fish of the sea, the birds of the
>   air, and all the living things that move on the earth."  29   God also
>   said: "See, I give you every seed-bearing plant all over the earth and
>   every tree that has seed-bearing fruit on it to be your food; 30 and
>   to all the animals of the land, all the birds of the air, and all the
>   living creatures that crawl on the ground, I give all the green plants
>   for food."  31 God looked at everything he had made, and he found it
>   very good. Evening came, and morning followed - the sixth day

Genesis 2

> 7  the LORD God formed man out of the clay of the ground and blew into
>   his nostrils the breath of life, and so man became a living being.  8 
>   Then the LORD God planted a garden in Eden, in the east, and he placed
>   there the man whom he had formed.  {snip}  21  So the LORD God cast a
>   deep sleep on the man, and while he was asleep, he took out one of his
>   ribs and closed up its place with flesh.  22  The LORD God then built
>   up into a woman the rib that he had taken from the man. When he
>   brought her to the man, 23  the man said: "This one, at last, is bone
>   of my bones and flesh of my flesh; This one shall be called 'woman,'
>   for out of 'her man' this one has been taken."  24  That is why a man
>   leaves his father and mother and clings to his wife, and the two of
>   them become one body.  25  The man and his wife were both naked, yet
>   they felt no shame.

While ejected from the Garden for disobedience, they did obey an earlier instruction to be fruitful and multiply.

Genesis Book 4

> 1  The man had relations with his wife Eve, and she conceived and bore
>   Cain, saying, "I have produced a man with the help of the LORD."  2 
>   Next she bore his brother Abel. Abel became a keeper of flocks, and
>   Cain a tiller of the soil.

Comment: You might want to edit your first sentence, for it sounds like you're saying Eve (and therefore all women) were not made in the image of God. Gen 1:27 is an interesting verse, but it shouldn't be taken to mean only the man was made in the image of God. "So God created mankind in his own image, in the image of God he created it, male and female he created them" is a good translation.

Comment: @curiousdannii Edited, good point.

Comment: You might also clarify that the Genesis account did not happen 2000 years ago according to the Bible

Comment: A good answer if you had no reason to believe the question is within scope, but I'm surprised  in this case that you did not notice that it is so clearly a Truth question.

Comment: @DickHarfield Or if it's a case of sheer ignorance.  The "seeker" discussions on meta informed my decision to answer.  Perhaps I erred.

Comment: I have no personal objection to any answers that seek to help possible converts, if that is what the site allows. At your implied suggestion, I searched meta for 'seeker' and found [this post](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/another-reason-this-is-not-a-christian-site) from David, our moderator: "*Would you really want this to be the place for a potential converts or new believers to learn about Truth? I wouldn't.* "  Sometimes I inadvertently answer Qs that are later judged out of scope, but I avoid the ones that clearly are :)